# Carousel View in Xamarin Forms NOT Loading different Templates

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

```
public DataTemplate CreateQuestionAnswerRadioButtonTemplate(string question, List<string> answers){

        DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            StackLayout parentLayout = new StackLayout()
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20),
                HeightRequest = 500,
            };
            ScrollView surveyScrollView = new ScrollView()
            {
                Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical,
            };
            StackLayout questionLayout = new StackLayout()
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5),
                HeightRequest = 500,
            };

            Label questLabel = new Label();
            questLabel.Text = question;
            questLabel.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#EF4D80");
            questLabel.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
            questLabel.FontSize = 18;
            BindableRadioGroup radioGroup = new BindableRadioGroup(false);
            radioGroup.ItemsSource = answers;
            questionLayout.Children.Add(questLabel);
            questionLayout.Children.Add(radioGroup);
            surveyScrollView.Content = questionLayout;
            parentLayout.Children.Add(surveyScrollView);
            return parentLayout;
        });
        return template;
    }
```

Adding these Data Templates to a List.

```
new CarouselView
        {
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0),
            ItemsSource = dataTemplates,
            ItemTemplate = dataTemplates[0],

        };
```

Now when I swipe the Carousel, How do I load dataTemplates[1 or 2 or 3] ??
I have a Next Button in which in am setting the item source of the Carousel View to dataTemplates[1] but the template does not get updated

Pls Suggest the right approach ?

```
            dataTemplates = new List<DataTemplate>();
dataTemplates.Add(CreateQuestionAnswerRadioButtonTemplate(Constants.SurveyQuestion_1, SurveyQuestion_1_Answers));
        dataTemplates.Add(CreateQuestionAnswerRadioButtonTemplate(Constants.SurveyQuestion_3, SurveyQuestion_3_Answers));
        dataTemplates.Add(CreateQuestionAnswerRadioButtonTemplate(Constants.SurveyQuestion_4, SurveyQuestion_4_Answers));
        dataTemplates.Add(CreateQuestionAnswerRadioButtonTemplate(Constants.SurveyQuestion_5, SurveyQuestion_5_Answers));
```

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you don't show what you tried and what exactly is not working

Comment: @DennisSchröer I have edited the same. Pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [DataTemplateSelector](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/) for your `CarouselView`.

---

### in your code behind of the page:

```
new CarouselView
{
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0),
    ItemsSource = dataTemplates,
    ItemTemplate = new SurveyDataTemplateSelector()
};
```

---

### SurveyDataTemplateSelector

```
DataTemplate survey1Template;
DataTemplate survey3Template;
DataTemplate survey4Template;
DataTemplate survey5Template;

public SurveyDataTemplateSelector()
{
    survey1Template = CreateQuestionAnswerRadioButtonTemplate(Constants.SurveyQuestion_1, SurveyQuestion_1_Answers);
    survey3Template = CreateQuestionAnswerRadioButtonTemplate(Constants.SurveyQuestion_3, SurveyQuestion_3_Answers);
    survey4Template = CreateQuestionAnswerRadioButtonTemplate(Constants.SurveyQuestion_4, SurveyQuestion_4_Answers);
    survey5Template = CreateQuestionAnswerRadioButtonTemplate(Constants.SurveyQuestion_5, SurveyQuestion_5_Answers);
}

protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
{
    // Here you define which DataTemplate is selected, for example:
    if (item == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    SurveyAnswers answers = item as SurveyAnswers;

    if (answers.question == 1)
    {
        return survey1Template;
    }
    else if (answers.question == 3)
    {
        return survey3Template;
    }
    else if (answers.question == 4)
    {
        return survey4Template;
    }
    else if (answers.question == 5)
    {
        return survey5Template;
    }

    return null; 
}
```

---

Check this link for a good documentation by Xamarin: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/

Comment: Thanks a ton @Dennis

Comment: In my carousel views, my templates contains buttons. How do I disable the sliding from Left-To-Right feature (Disable Gesture). "InputTransparent" de-activates the Buttons too. but how to stop gesture sliding. @Dennis pls help